# Is requestAction in cakephp is a post method?

Tags: http, cakephp, post

I am trying to send the data by POST Method in controller. i found `requestAction()`and `$HttpSocket->post` as a solutions .But not sure which is better and why?

Comment: http://api.cakephp.org/2.8/class-Object.html#_requestAction

Comment: What version of cakephp are you using??

Comment: cakephp 2.5.1. i am using

Answer (score 0):

If you going to be cross controller communicating, then you need to use requestAction.

Comment: is it similar to cURL